# Download Words with Friends chat logs?

Tags: words-with-friends

Is there any way I can download my Word with Friends chat logs (short 
of bringing up the chat window and cutting and pasting)?

Comment: If you pop up the chat window and then click "save frame as", you get the contents of the chat (+ a lot of other garbage).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I've found is to take screen shots. Saves a lot of time.